# R plotting over a rendered plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, r-sf

I have a base plot which i want to overlay some data over (i will create multiple plots overlaying the same base plot) and was wondering if there was a way to "pre-render" and save the base plot, then to plot some data over later, to save rendering time.

My current code looks like this:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

...

base_plot <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = coast) + 
  geom_sf(data = roads) + 
  theme_bw() +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=longlat +zone=33", xlim = c(10.54433, 10.92609), ylim = c(59.88134, 59.98148), expand = FALSE, datum = NA)

base_plot + geom_sf(data = some.data_1)
base_plot + geom_sf(data = some.data_2)
...
```

Comment: Once the plot has been built or rendered, you can't really add any data anymore to the plot, since the scales (x/y-axis,  colours, fills) have been trained on the data. You could try to do some gtable voodoo, but that still has to be drawn so it is more pre-interpreted than pre-rendered.

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could save your base plot as a png and then plot on top of that. I've done this with published figures to show I can replicate them - getting the axes to match up is hard. Only worth considering if you have a lot of plots and they take a very long time to render

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I found a walkaround to the problem, I exported the shapefiles and imported them to qgis instead.